# Passing a type to a Record

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a number of types

```
type RoseType = {
 cmd: "rose",
 color: "red" | "white",
 height: number
}

type DandelionType = {
 cmd: "dandelion",
 color: "yellow",
 leaves: number
}

type FlowerTypes = RoseType | DandelionType;
```

I am trying to make a record out of them in a factory function:

```
getFlowerFromFactory<
T extends FlowerTypes["cmd"]>(cmd: T): string {
const factories: Record<T, string> = {
  dandelion: "1",
  rose:  "2"
};
return factories[cmd];
```

}

But the code breaks, not allowing the generic argument T in the Record, as I get the message

```
TS2322: Type '{ dandelion: string; rose: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<T, 
string>'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'dandelion' does not exist 
in type 'Record<T, string>'.
```

This is a very boiled down example, I know. What I am actually doing is a factory function that should be able to take its parameters from the FlowerType types, but I am really stuck on this one thing. What is typescript telling me here? The type of T is "dandelion | rose" isn't it? My IDE is auto-completing the "rose" and "dandelion" just fine. If I change Record to

```
Record<FlowerTypes["cmd"], string>
```

Then it works, but I will get trouble down the line as I will not have a binding between the function argument and the Record.

Why does the generic argument not work? And what can i do to get something out of the generic argument that Record can accept?

Comment: Excess property checks are being applied here. Since `T` may not necessarily include `rose`, `rose` is not allowed (likewise for `dandelion`). And what you mean "binding between the function argument and the Record"? You're returning `string` right now, which has no relation to `T`. Are you asking to somehow relate it?